# auto-replacing my dash makes me sad

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

I am working in Open Office Writer 3.3.0 and I have come across something a bit odd.
When I write a semi-mathematical formula my "-" gets replaced by a "–", a slightly longer dash, and I cannot seem to turn it off in the autocorrect. I am not sure how to.
the dash "-" does not appear in the autocorrect table of any language, whereas double-dash "--" does.

Any ideas how to disable this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't appear in the `Replace` list, because it is an option on its own.

To disable it, go to

```
Tools -> AutoCorrect Options... -> Options
```

and uncheck `Replace dashes`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This just saved my life.

Comment: Why would they do this in the first place, why!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a temporary solution to avoid this whenever it happens. Press 'Ctrl+Z' to undo changing the 'dash'