# How to stop OpenOffice 4 from replacing your -- double-dash with a single long dash

Tags: openoffice, find-and-replace

I was trying to document some command lines in Linux that use a double dash --option-name and was annoyed that OpenOffice/LibreOffice was replacing the double-dash with a single long dash (U+2013).

So, the question is "How do I stop OpenOffice/LibreOffice 4 from replacing my double-dashes?"

Note: My searches led me to [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/439726/auto-replacing-my-dash-makes-me-sad) that was not quite the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

In OpenOffice 4 (I am on Linux using OpenOffice version 4.2.8.2):

There is a setting:

Tool --> AutoCorrect Options --> Replace

To remove the effective entry at the top of the Replace tab:

1) Select the line that specifies the double-dash replacement (in this case the highlighted line at the top)
2) Click the Delete button on the right
3) Click "OK" at the bottom of the window

[image: screenshot of Replace tab showing the top line for dash replacement and the delete button]

If you are trying to turn off replacement of single dashes, look at this other SU question: ["auto-replacing my dash makes me sad"](https://superuser.com/questions/439726/auto-replacing-my-dash-makes-me-sad)